# Dropping a table with Visual Studio 2013 Database Project

Tags: database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, database-project

I have a database project but when I publish, the generated script never generate any drop for any table but when I create table, It does generate the create script.

I have taken a look on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799802/dropping-a-table-with-visual-studio-2010-database-project) but it's not the same since It was visual stuido 2010. can anyone help with visual studio 2013?

Comment: Did you checked that option not present in vs2013?

Comment: Yes, I couldn't even find deploy tab in vs2013

Comment: Most probably the tab name is `Publish` and not deploy.

Comment: doesn't exist also, there is only a command if I clicked right click on the project called publish but there is no tab for it

Comment: No, right click on project and select properties (the last option). there you will find publish tab.

Comment: If you right-click the project, select "Publish". In that window, select "Advanced" and verify that the option to drop objects not in the project is selected. You can then save that as a "Publish Profile" file in your project so you don't have to repeat steps in the future.  I am not aware of a "publish" tab anywhere in properties.

Comment: @PeterSchott I have also tried that but never generate drop table in the generated script after publishing ... I think it's a bug in visual studio